# Prove that $(x+y)^{p^m}=x^{p^m}+y^{p^m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

This is an exercise from the book *Introduction to algebra* by А. И. КОСТРИКИН.

> Assume $p$ is a prime, $R$ is a communicative ring with identity element, such that $\forall x\in R, px=0$. Prove that
> $$
> (x+y)^{p^m}=x^{p^m}+y^{p^m}, \quad m=1,2,\ldots 
> $$

My attempt was to make induction on $m$, but I failed to find the right way to proceed.

Comment: Can't you use binomial theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way to prove it using induction is to assume that it holds for all $m$ such that $1\le m\le n$ and for some given $n$. To show that it holds for $n+1$, we should prove
$$
(x+y)^{p^{n+1}}=x^{^{p^{n+1}}}+y^{^{p^{n+1}}}
$$
*proof*

Note that
$$
(x+y)^{p^{n+1}}{=
\left[(x+y)^{p^{n}}\right]^p\\
=\left[x^{p^n}+y^{p^n}\right]^p\\
=(x^{p^n})^p+(y^{p^n})^p\\
=x^{p^{n+1}}+y^{p^{n+1}}
}
$$
Done!

Answer (score 2):

Induction helps because if $(x+y)^{p^k}=x^{p^k}+y^{p^k}$ then$$(x+y)^{p^{k+1}}=(x^{p^k}+y^{p^k})^p=(x^{p^k})^p+(y^{p^k})^p,$$provided we've proven the base step $m=1$. @J.W.Tanner hinted checking the base step with$$(x+y)^p-x^p-y^p=\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{j}x^jy^{p-j}.$$Each binomial coefficient has a factor of $p$ in its numerator $p!$, but not its denominator $j!(p-j)!$, so is divisible by $p$.